# " Error in connection" when use insert command to access db with ado.net C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ado.net

I write code to insert some values to access database with C#/ado.net but there is an error appear called "error in connection" although i use select command to retrieve  some valuesin the same program  and works successfully

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mohamed\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Library Store\Library Store\Book.accdb");

conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Store VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", ISBNTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", NameTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", GategoryTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", AuthorTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", int.Parse(CostTB.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(" Done :)");
conn.Close();
```

thanks;

Comment: What's the full text and type of the error?  Is there an inner exception?

Comment: @val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6 are all your column in Database?

Comment: Be sure to click [Copy Execption Detial to Clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png) and paste the text it copied here in side a set of `<pre></pre>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot, you didn't specify what error it was but this should help you out if anythign figure out if you really have all columns your trying to insert to

Try writing you sql statement like so

INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )

---

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=C:\Users\Mohamed\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Library Store\Library     Store\Book.accdb");

conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Store **( Column1, Column2 )** VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", ISBNTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", NameTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", GategoryTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", AuthorTB.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val5", int.Parse(CostTB.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val6", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(" Done :)");
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column names in your insert statement so that the DB knows where the data is going.

```
"INSERT INTO Store (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@val1, @val2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert value to database with all column you can use this query

```
INSERT INTO Store  VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)
```

If you insert value to database with few column you will get this error, and you must write it as

```
INSERT INTO Store **( Column1, Column2 )** VALUES(@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4,@val5,@val6)
```